# When I am deleting files from var folder It is giving error

Tags: magento-2.1, exception, code-generation

I have installed two **Magento's** at my live server of **version 2.1.7 & 2.1.8** When I am deleting some files from `/Var` folder it is giving me error in my system like bellow

**In CMD**

```
[Exception]
  Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/av
  iansrollplug/public_html/alpha/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Enti
  tyAbstract.php on line 152
```

**On site**

```
RuntimeException: Source class "" for "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor" generation does not exist. in magento_root/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:185
```

I have deleted the below folders from `/var` folder

```
var/Cache
var/generation
var/page_cache
var/tmp
var/view_processed
```

Why it is happening? When I had deleted it first time in normal way (let it be present in trash) it was working but when I deleted it completely that it should not store any data into trash then it started generating this error

Please If any one can help into this?Where I need to do changes? I didn't altered anything into the core files of **Magento**

Comment: Do you set the permission to the `var` folder?

Comment: In what mode is your site running? Run command `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` to check this. Also see the docs on this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

Comment: do you have run the commad: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I am running in developer mode & when I ran any command of magento it is giving that it is not existing into it & generates the CMD command given in my question & yes I tried to run the `setup:static-content:deploy` command as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the folders, delete the content of the folders.
I just tested this in M2.1.9 and got the same error.

You can use your OS file browser, but I'd recommend using the command line. Here is an example for Linux/Mac:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/tmp/* var/view_processed/*
```

If you're unfamiliar with the above command you should be very careful not to type it incorrectly and accidentally delete the wrong folder (or **worse**, everything, i.e. `/`).

Also good to know, if you run `rm -rf pub/static/*` will delete all but hidden files, such as `pub/static/.htaccess`. It wasn't in your example but you might run into it down the road.

To fix your current situation recreate the folders. A permission fix might be necessary. For me, some content was partially generated and the error stuck around, so I ended up having to clear the `var/generation` folder again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give full permission to this folder

did you try `chmod -R 777 var`  ?

it will allow magento to re-generate those folder and content inside it